# What do I need to know before switching from Qt to Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I've been using Qt since I started to learn C++. It was the recommended SDK by professor so I didn't try another. Now that I want to learn to use Visual C++, it confuses me what the differences between those two SDKs are. I grew quite comfortable with all the signal and slot stuff of Qt. I wonder if I can find similar functionality in Visual C++. If for any chance, is there any tutorial that teaches you how to work with Visual C++?

Comment: @Sayem Ahmed:Thanks for reminding. I was not aware that I could choose the answer. I thought the most upvoted answer would be automatically promoted.

Comment: I can tell you I switched the other way (after 15 years of MFC) and I was very thankful of that. Although there are parts of Qt that are similar enough that the switch was not terribly hard. I design and build all of my Qt applications under Visual Studio using CMake as the project generator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qt is a user interface library written in C++, available on multiple platforms; Visual C++ is a Windows IDE produced by Microsoft. They aren't really comparable -- in fact, I'm pretty sure that, if you felt like it, you could develop an application in Visual C++ which used Qt.

If what you are actually thinking of is the native Windows UI library, that's called MFC (Microsoft Framework Class). It's about 20 years old (!!) now, and contains a lot of historical quirks (including the STRING one which Neel Basu mentioned above); unless you specifically need to learn it, I would strongly recommend that you learn something else instead. If you want to learn one of Windows' native UI libraries, WinForms and WPF are more current, but are based on .NET, not C++. If you want to learn another C++ based UI library, you might want to try out wxWidgets; like Qt, wxWidgets is cross-platform.

Comment: I also recommend wxWidgets if you need to use C++.

Comment: wxWidgets' design follows MFC. So suggesting to learn wxWidgets after ranting about MFC's quirks seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is the Visual C++ help and the MS documentation on MFC and other component frameworks that MS provides